# XCode9: XCUITest gives Runner UIAccessibility Error

Tags: testing, xcode9, xcode-ui-testing, uiaccessibility, xcuitest

I'm getting a lot of error when run XCUITests on real device:

> Runner [AXValidations] UIAccessibility Error adding -[PHAsset
>   accessibilityLabel] Runner [AXValidations] UIAccessibility Error
>   adding -[PLManagedAsset accessibilityLabel] Runner[AXValidations]
>   UIAccessibility Error adding -[PLManagedaAsset accessibilityValue]
>   Runner [AXValidations] UIAccessibility Error adding -[PLManagedAsset
>   accessibilityTraits] Runner[AXValidations] UIAccessibility Error
>   adding -[PLManagedAsset _accessibilityPhotoDescription] Runner
>   [AXValidations] UIAccessibility Error adding +[PLManagedAsset
>   safeCategoryBaseClass]

It slow down the tests. Also I don't see these errors running tests on simulators.

Answer (score 1):

While I don't have a proper solution at hand, nor do I know the real issue that's going on -- restarting not only Xcode, but also the whole device, got me rid of these messages.

Hopefully this is OK as a proposed answer, since there's nothing else.